# Info about a direct tcp/ip connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tcp

Trying to get info about creating and using a direct `TCP/IP` connection to SQL Server. No .NET., no ODBC, no OLE, and no 3rd party library, unless available in source. No SQL Native Client. Barebones. Any pointers?

Comment: You'll need to write a TDS protocol handler to manage the session.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx for the specs.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Thanks. I take your point. In your opinion, what is the least intrusive and most easily installed client-side library or program to handle the connection? Or better, embedded into the app?

Comment: Much depends on the OS and development language. With a Windows .NET app, .NET, SqlClient is already installed and provides very efficient SQL Server data access.  ODBC is appropriate for unmanaged (e.g. C++) access from Windows and others like Linux. Although the legacy "SQL Server" ODBC driver is available with a Windows OS without a separate install, it is best to install and use the latest SQL Server driver, "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server".  ODBC Driver 13 is in preview.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt703139(v=sql.1).aspx.